# C#- Selenium Webdriver, Not able to select radiobutton as a label is displayed over it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium webdriver and i am using C# to write the script.
I have a field Gender having Male and Female option, these options are actually radio buttons but are displayed like labels.

I tried million ways to have it selected:

1. driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[value='Female']")).Click();
2. driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@value,'Male']")).Click();
3. driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='radio'][value='Male']")).Click();
4. driver.FindElement (By.XPath ("//input[@value='Female']")).Click ();

But **NONE** worked from above.
The html for the Gender fields looks like this:

```html
<li class="radiobutton-yesno ui-buttonset">
 <span class="label">
 Gender                        
  <span class="help-icon" data-title="Your gender is a factor in determining your cost.">
  </span>
 </span>
 <input type="radio" id="genderNo_1" name="gender_1" value="Male" class="reqCntrl ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
  <label for="genderNo_1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Male</span>
  </label>
 <input type="radio" id="genderYes_1" name="gender_1" value="Female" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
  <label for="genderYes_1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" role="button">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Female</span>
  </label>
</li>
```

and the field on page appears like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJoWM.png)

Comment: Can any one please help me with this as i am not able to find a way out to proceed

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` type is probably being hidden via css/js rules. So you can't click on those - Selenium doesn't let you do something that a user can't.

The `@value` attribute also belongs to the radiobutton `<input>`s so using that in the selector won't work, since that entire element is hidden.

Instead, use the `<label>` or the `<span>` under label and match with it's text:

1. `//label/span[text()='Female']`
2. `//label/span[text()='Male']`

PS: this is a bit worrying wrt the nature of this question:

> "Your gender is a factor in determining your cost."

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label/span[text()='Female']")).Click(); - it didn't work. Then when i tried with driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label/span[contains(.,'Male')]")).Click(); - it worked once, but when i tried reexecuting it is not working at all. Not able to figured out what is the problem. Can any one suggest any other alternative?

Comment: I have to eventually insert javascript and it worked. I looped through all label tags on the page, and then used childnode property to select the span tag under it.

Comment: Then you should post your solution as an answer so that other SO visitors may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good UX practice to put radio inside a label. Try to change your markup to obey that rule. After that you should be able to select radio by performing click action on the label (select label by text as @aneroid shown you).

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what error Selenium is throwing?

You can try using a script instead.

```
var temp = "var elt = document.getElementById('#myRadioButton'); elt.click();";
driver.executeScript(temp);
```

Comment: Yes i had used js and it solved the issue. Anyways, thanks.